# Why is double bracket used to 'ensure' some commands, since it is not a logical check for "does it exist or not' (false/true)?

Tags: shell-script, syntax

Recently I've been trying to figure out more and more shell syntax and logic behind some lines within scripts and I have the following question:
What is the purpose of `[[expression]]` in the example since it brings no value to the executed line and can thus be skipped and done just with the actual expression after `[[]]`?.

```
export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

My presumption is that it is some kind of check in case some value is missing (Null pointer exception) , but I don't think the `"[[]]"` operators does something like that?
Goal of the script is simple => to export `sdk` to be available globally from the terminal.

Comment: what would the alternative code be? i.e. which part exactly would you remove as bringing no value? Do you know what `[[ .. ]]` in general does?

Comment: The reason behind the "I did not get what value they bring to the expression" is that I thought that '-s exp" == 'source exp' .  I thought -s was a shortcut to source but apparently wasn't. Check @Stephen Kitt's answer. That is what I was asking for. I did not understand why it was used as I thought it was simply a repeat of the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-s file` [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html) checks whether the named file exists and is not empty. The [`[[…]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b) compound command exits with an appropriate status depending on the evaluation of the expression inside the double brackets.

Thus

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

only sources `$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh` if it exists and is not empty.

(I’m assuming `export SDKMAN_DIR="$HOME/.sdkman"` is on a separate line.)

Comment: I see, I thought it was an equivalent to "source" since it started with '-s' but I should have checked that first, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On my local machine (and from experience) '[' is an alias in bash for /usr/bin/test. Clearly `[[` does *not* expand to `/usr/bin/test/usr/bin/test` (because there's no space between). In bash (and possibly other shells) double square brackets are a reserved word that use the shells internal expression evaluator rather than calling /usr/bin/test.

The code here executes `$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh` in the current shell if the file has a non-zero length after setting a variable. I have no idea what the intention of doing this is (since a zero length file wouldn't actually do anything).

Comment: Hello, I was thinking whether the -s and source were the same actually, but @Stephen KItt's answer explained it.  Mainly that is where the confusion came from.

Comment: In `bash`, both `[` and `test` are shell built-ins, not aliases. You can confirm with `type [`.